# Como pegar o texto, em elemento CSS recebendo 2 classe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Preciso coletar texto de um sistema em angular, onde o elemento recebe 2 classes CSS

```
<div class="title ng-scope">80</div>
```

Testei diversas formas de capturar o texto, porém não retorna (as linhas comentadas mostra as tentativas)

Código em python, usando PhantomJS e Selenium abaixo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

try:
    url_reputacao = driver.get("http://rdash.github.io/#/")
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('title ng-scope')
    #element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("title ng-scope")
    #element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='title ng-scope']")
    #element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.widget-icon green pull-left ng-scope > div.title ng-scope").text
    #element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'title ng-scope')]")

    print(element.text)
    driver.quit()

except Exception as erro:
    data = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot-%s.png' % data)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danilo,

analisando melhor a página que você passou, no `Chrome`, ao `inspecionar` o item `"80 Users"`, clicar na aba `Network` e depois em `XHR` e em `JS`, ao refazer o `request` ao site (`F5`), pude entender por onde e quando os dados são passados ao template.

Ao entrar no link [dashboard.html](http://rdash.github.io/templates/dashboard.html), podemos encontrar o valor que você quer, sem precisar utilizar a biblioteca `Selenium` (o que agiliza e muito o processo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://rdash.github.io/templates/dashboard.html'
html_source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

users = soup.find('div', {'class':'title'})
print(users.text)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> 80
```

---

***Obs.:*** Dê um `print(soup.prettify()))` e procure a linha `<i class="fa fa-users"></i></div><div class=title>80</div><div class=comment>Users</div>` para verificar que esse número `80` realmente é referente aos usuários. 
Também poderia ter utilizado o `i class fa fa-users` para localizar o valor ou o `div` com o texto `Users`, por exemplo.